# Scala/Spark Compilation on IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, apache-spark

I have a simple scala app on IntelliJ but that just prints a line but whenever I try to compile it I'm getting

> Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
>   Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.10.0-52.0'
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
>       at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
>       at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
>       at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:33)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
>       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

I'm using Scala 2.10 and Spark 1.2.0 is listed as a dependency.

Anybody have any idea how I can get this to compile? Thanks!

Comment: you really should provide the code and your build script

Comment: Sorry. I've only recently been using IntelliJ to code and I don't really know what to put in terms of scripts. My build.sbt contains:

`name := "shuriken"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"`

All that's in the code I'm trying to test is a println("Hello") inside the main function. I added the scala-sdk-2.10.0 to the module dependencies.

Comment: Got it now thanks. It was apparently a problem with scala 2.10.0 I used 2.10.4.

Comment: @inomant Using newer 2.10.x is indeed the solution.